# Django 1.4: admin not using STATIC_URL

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles, django-1.4

I've upgrade my Django from 1.3 to 1.4, and using `django.contrib.staticfiles`.
I have to change the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to only use `STATIC_URL`, wich is defined as `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

When I open the admin interface, css files are linked to /admin/css/base.css, but, if I'm correct, they should point to static/admin/css/base.css

Don't know why my admin interface is omitting the `static_url`.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this but try commenting out the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` defined in settings.py as it has been deprecated in django 1.4[1] 
[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin

Comment: Sorry, I have already deleted `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` because it has been deprecated. That is what I mean with "have to chage the ... to only use"